# C# Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application") Error

Tags: c#, powerpoint, administrator

I'm working on a tool to get running power point program and control it so 
i used this code to get reference of running program.

```
 var pptApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```

But it throws this erorr

```
Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
```

I noticed that was happening because my app was running as administrator but power point wasn't and when i run my app as normal it works, but i need it as administrator

Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: why your app is running as admin?

Comment: I need it for other functions in my app

Comment: well this function need a medium IL process. You need to move the admin-only code to another process. there is no way you can do both in the same process.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe i'll do it but how i could run a process with non adminstrator from an admin app ??

Comment: have a medium il launcher. then run the admin app or the office interop app when necessary.